# Play Framework: EhCache issue on every code hot compile

Tags: scala, caching, playframework

In Play 2.5.3, using Scala:

I'm using cache as a module, and every time I change the code and then refresh my browser, after the recompile I am getting the following issue:

```
[TechnicalException: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error in custom provider, play.api.cache.EhCacheExistsException: An EhCache instance with name 'play' already exists.

This usually indicates that multiple instances of a dependent component (e.g. a Play application) have been started at the same time.

  at play.api.cache.EhCacheModule.play$api$cache$EhCacheModule$$bindCache$1(Cache.scala:184):
Binding(interface net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache qualified with QualifierInstance(@play.cache.NamedCache(value=play)) to ProviderTarget(play.api.cache.NamedEhCacheProvider@2dfe19e7)) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
  while locating net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache annotated with @play.cache.NamedCache(value=play)
  at play.api.cache.EhCacheModule.play$api$cache$EhCacheModule$$bindCache$1(Cache.scala:185):
Binding(interface play.api.cache.CacheApi qualified with QualifierInstance(@play.cache.NamedCache(value=play)) to ProviderTarget(play.api.cache.NamedCacheApiProvider@6f7b9e34)) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
  while locating play.api.cache.CacheApi annotated with @play.cache.NamedCache(value=play)
  while locating play.api.cache.CacheApi
    for parameter 0 at play.cache.DefaultCacheApi.<init>(DefaultCacheApi.java:20)
  at play.cache.DefaultCacheApi.class(DefaultCacheApi.java:20)
  while locating play.cache.DefaultCacheApi
  while locating play.cache.CacheApi

1 error]
```

I am using cache (a named one, not the default `play`) for a few actors. How could I solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Post your `application.conf`

Comment: Can you show how you are creating/configuring that cache?

Answer (score 0):

Did you disable EHCache?

In `application.conf`:-

```
# disable default Play framework cache plugin
play.modules.disabled += "play.api.cache.EhCacheModule"
```

Comment: disabling cache does not solve the problem when you or your dependencies need the cacheApi

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in newer post [EhCache instance with name 'play' already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43243293/ehcache-instance-with-name-play-already-exists/48120583#48120583). It's only workaround but it works, key part is:

```
 lifecycle.addStopHook { () =>
    logger.info("CacheInstance stopped")
    Future.successful(CacheManager.getInstance().shutdown())
  }
```

Set the post for the full code.