# EhCache instance with name 'play' already exists

Tags: playframework, couchbase, ehcache, playframework-2.5, playframework-2.6

I faced the issue with the **Play framework** default cache (**EHCache**) when working with asynchronous **couchdatabase** java driver. Play crashes on the hot reload with the error:

```
Error in custom provider, play.api.cache.EhCacheExistsException: An EhCache instance with name 'play' already exists.
```

I found this could be not only with the **couchdatabase** driver but also in some other scenarios, like https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pac4j-dev/2_EUOCrov7M.

Answer (score 4):

I figure out a solution - force cache shutdown on the stop hook. It could be done in one of an existent module in your project like:

```
lifecycle.addStopHook(() -> {
  ...
  CacheManager.getInstance().shutdown();
  ...
});
```

Special "fix" module could be created as well:

```
package fixes;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Singleton;

import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;

import net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager;
import play.Logger;
import play.Logger.ALogger;
import play.inject.ApplicationLifecycle;

/**
 * Fix for the hot reloading cache issue.
 * "Error in custom provider, play.api.cache.EhCacheExistsException: An EhCache instance with name 'play' already exists."
 *
 */
public class CacheFix  extends AbstractModule{  
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(CacheFixInstance.class).asEagerSingleton();        
    }
}


/**
 * Only stop hook
 */
@Singleton
class CacheFixInstance {    
    private static ALogger logger = Logger.of(CacheFixInstance.class);

    @Inject
    public CacheFixInstance(ApplicationLifecycle lifecycle) {
        lifecycle.addStopHook(() -> {

            // Force cache to stop.
            CacheManager.getInstance().shutdown();
            logger.debug("Cache has been shutdown");

            // Nothing to return.
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
        });
    }
}
```

In `application.conf` :

```
enabled += fixes.CacheFix
```

Answer (score 1):

In case some look to a quick copypaste fix here is the scala version I translated from Andriy Kuba's answer

```
package utils

import javax.inject.{Inject, Singleton}

import com.google.inject.AbstractModule
import net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager
import play.api.Logger
import play.api.inject.ApplicationLifecycle

import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}

/**
  * Fix for the hot reloading cache issue.
  * "Error in custom provider, play.api.cache.EhCacheExistsException: An EhCache instance with name 'play' already exists."
  *
  */
class CacheHotReloadFix extends AbstractModule {
  override protected def configure(): Unit = {
    bind(classOf[CacheHotReloadFixInstance]).asEagerSingleton()
  }
}

@Singleton
class CacheHotReloadFixInstance @Inject() (lifecycle: ApplicationLifecycle, implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContext) {

  private val logger = Logger(this.getClass)

  lifecycle.addStopHook { () =>
    logger.debug("Forching ehcach to stop before play reloads")
    // Force cache to stop.
    Future(CacheManager.getInstance().shutdown())
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this with play 2.6.3. Did not fix the error.

Comment: @nemoo if you are having the issue with test cases, please see my answer below.

Comment: Worked in 2.5.6. 2.5.3 Has a bug so stophooks do not work

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble while running the test cases (where there will be multiple `Applicaiton`s), you can have a dummy implementation of the `SyncCacheApi` and `AsyncCacheApi` and override the bindings while creating the `Application` via `provideApplication()`

```
    @Override
    protected Application provideApplication() {
Application application = new GuiceApplicationBuilder().configure(testConfig)
                        .disable(EhCacheModule.class)
    .overrides(bind(SyncCacheApi.class).to(FakeSyncCacheApi.class))
                        .bindings(new MyModule())
                        .in(new File(".")).build();
     return application;
}
```

and the sample `FakeSyncCacheApi` would be something like

```
@Singleton
public class FakeSyncCacheApi implements SyncCacheApi {

    private LRUMap cache = new LRUMap();

    @Override
    public <T> T get(String key) {
        return (T) cache.get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T getOrElseUpdate(String key, Callable<T> block, int expiration) {
        return getOrElseUpdate(key, block);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T getOrElseUpdate(String key, Callable<T> block) {
        T value = (T) cache.get(key);
        if (value == null) {
            try {
                value = block.call();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            cache.put(key, value);
        }
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public void set(String key, Object value, int expiration) {
        cache.put(key, value);
    }

    @Override
    public void set(String key, Object value) {
        cache.put(key, value);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(String key) {
        cache.remove(key);
    }
}
```

The idea here is to disable the `EhCache` module and have our own dummy implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Scala version based on Andriy Kubas version that works with Play 2.5.6. Remember that Play 2.5.3 has a bug, so stophooks doesn't work.

```
package modules

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

import com.google.inject._
import net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager;

import play.api.Logger
import play.api.inject.ApplicationLifecycle
import play.api.{ Configuration, Environment, Mode }
import play.api.inject.{ Module => PlayModule }

class CacheModule extends PlayModule {

  def bindings(environment: Environment, configuration: Configuration) = Seq(
    bind[CacheFixInstance].toSelf.eagerly
  )
}

@Singleton
class CacheFixInstance @Inject()(lifecycle: ApplicationLifecycle) {
  val logger = Logger(this.getClass)

  lifecycle.addStopHook { () =>
    logger.info("CacheInstance stopped")
    Future.successful(CacheManager.getInstance().shutdown())
  }

}
```

and ofcourse `play.modules.enabled += "modules.CacheModule"`

Answer (score 0):

For me adding a shutdown hook did not work (maybe not fast enough, I don't know). Instead I'd just shutdown the CacheManager at the end of each test suite and run them sequentially:

```
override def afterAll(): Unit = {
  CacheManager.getInstance().shutdown()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution to the problem for Scala and Play 2.6 based on [Andriy Kuba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1118419/andriy-kuba) answer.

First it is required to include `javaCore` module in `build.sbt` to be able to import `play.api.inject.ApplicationLifecycle`

```
  libraryDependencies += javaCore
```

Then create a new class `CacheFixInstance.scala`:

```
package util

import javax.inject.Inject
import net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager
import play.api.Logger
import play.api.inject.ApplicationLifecycle

import scala.concurrent.Future

class CacheFixInstance @Inject()(lifecycle: ApplicationLifecycle) {

  private val logger = Logger(getClass)

  lifecycle.addStopHook { () =>
    logger.info("CacheInstance stopped")
    Future.successful(CacheManager.getInstance().shutdown())
  }

  logger.info(s"Hot reload EHCache fix initialized.")
}
```

and then add it to your module configuration or alternativelly use `@singleton` annotation to `CacheFixInstance` class:

```
bind(classOf[CacheFixInstance]).asEagerSingleton()
```